# Uploading .txt files to firebase storage from Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

So far, after some research from the internet I have been able to select .jpeg files from the computer and upload it to the firebase using Unity C#.

But, I cannot figure out, how I should modify the code below to use it for uploading .txt files as well.

If there is some other simpler way to do this task please tell that (if any). Otherwise, tell how I should modify this code so that it fulfills the purpose mentioned above.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//For Picking files
using System.IO;
using SimpleFileBrowser;

//For firebase storage
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using Firebase.Storage;
public class UploadFile : MonoBehaviour
{
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    FileBrowser.SetFilters(true, new FileBrowser.Filter("Images", ".jpg", ".png"), new FileBrowser.Filter("Text Files", ".txt", ".pdf"));

    FileBrowser.SetDefaultFilter(".jpg");


    FileBrowser.SetExcludedExtensions(".lnk", ".tmp", ".zip", ".rar", ".exe");
    storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    storageReference = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://app_name.appspot.com/");


}

public void OnButtonClick()
{
    StartCoroutine(ShowLoadDialogCoroutine());

}

IEnumerator ShowLoadDialogCoroutine()
{

    yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(FileBrowser.PickMode.FilesAndFolders, true, null, null, "Load Files and Folders", "Load");

    Debug.Log(FileBrowser.Success);

    if (FileBrowser.Success)
    {
        // Print paths of the selected files (FileBrowser.Result) (null, if FileBrowser.Success is false)
        for (int i = 0; i < FileBrowser.Result.Length; i++)
            Debug.Log(FileBrowser.Result[i]);

        Debug.Log("File Selected");
        byte[] bytes = FileBrowserHelpers.ReadBytesFromFile(FileBrowser.Result[0]);
        //Editing Metadata
        var newMetadata = new MetadataChange();
        newMetadata.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        //Create a reference to where the file needs to be uploaded
        StorageReference uploadRef = storageReference.Child("uploads/newFile.jpeg");
        Debug.Log("File upload started");
        uploadRef.PutBytesAsync(bytes, newMetadata).ContinueWithOnMainThread((task) => {
            if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("File Uploaded Successfully!");
            }
        });


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it is basically already working as expected but you need to handle the different file types / extensions differently.

I think all you need to actually do is

- use the correct file name + extension
- use the correct `ContentType` depending on the file extension

So maybe something like

```
IEnumerator ShowLoadDialogCoroutine()
{
    yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(FileBrowser.PickMode.FilesAndFolders, true, null, null, "Load Files and Folders", "Load");

    Debug.Log(FileBrowser.Success);

    if (!FileBrowser.Success)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    //foreach (var file in FileBrowser.Result)
    //{
    //    Debug.Log(file);
    //}

    var file = FileBrowser.Result[0];

    Debug.Log("File Selected: \"{file}\"");

    // e.g. C:\someFolder/someFile.txt => someFile.txt
    var fileNameWithExtension = file.Split('/', '\\').Last();

    if (!fileNameWithExtension.Contains('.'))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Selected file \"{file}\" is not a supported file!");
    }

    // e.g. someFile.txt => txt
    var extensionWithoutDot = fileNameWithExtension.Split('.').Last();

    // Get MIME type according to file extension
    var contentType = extensionWithoutDot switch
    {
        "jpg" => $"image/jpeg",
        "jpeg" => $"image/jpeg",
        "png" => $"image/png",
        "txt" => "text/plain",
        "pdf" => "application/pdf",
        _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Selected file \"{file}\" of type \"{extensionWithoutDot}\" is not supported!")
    };

    // Use dynamic content / MIME type
    var newMetadata = new MetadataChange()
    {
        ContentType = contentType
    };

    // Use the actual selected file name including extension
    StorageReference uploadRef = storageReference.Child($"uploads/{fileNameWithExtension}");
    Debug.Log("File upload started");
    uploadRef.PutBytesAsync(bytes, newMetadata).ContinueWithOnMainThread((task) =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogException(task.Exception);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"File \"{file}\" Uploaded Successfully!");
        }
    });
}
```

you most probably will want to replace the `throw` by proper error handling with user feedback later ;)